# How to hide/show elements in Bootstrap grid and have the position update

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback" style="width:250px">
        <label class="control-label sr-only" for="SearchTB">Hidden Label</label>
        <input type="text" ID="SearchTB" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="FilterTextBox();" autofocus="true" class="form-control" /> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <h2>Project LRE</h2>

            <p>Latest Revised Estimated for Projects, used by Finance.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/ProjectLRE" role="button">View Site &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <h2>TERMUS</h2>

            <p>TERMUS online appraisal system.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/TERMUS" role="button">View Site &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <h2>Call Logs</h2>

            <p>Online system for reporting calls to comply with FOCI rules.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/CallLogs" role="button">View Site &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <h2>Call Logs (Mobile)</h2>

            <p>Mobile optimized site for reporting calls to comply with FOCI rules.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/CallLogsMobile" role="button">View Site &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <h2>Visit Requests &amp; Contact Reports</h2>

            <p>Managed visit requests and contact reports to comply with FOCI rules.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/VisitRequests" role="button">View Site &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <h2>Quick Reports Scheduler</h2>

            <p>Schedule Quick Reports from IFS to be delivered to automatically delivered to you on a schedule.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/QuickReports" role="button">View Site &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    function FilterResults(filtertext) {
    $(".col-md-4").each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(element).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(filtertext.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
            $(element).show();
        } else {
            $(element).hide();
        }
    });
}

function FilterTextBox() {
    FilterResults($("#SearchTB").val());
}
```

The goal is that this textbox will show/hide elements based on the enter text. This works, but due to the way I defined the rows with Bootstrap, the elements are still tied to the rows they were defined on instead of reordering dynamically. I'm still learning Bootstrap and don't know how to get them so that the search results appear in the first available "slot". How should I do that?

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bHVf/12/). Search for `call` and I think you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible to just drop the declaration of the new row.

Delete the second `<div class="row">` so that more than 3 elements are in your grid row.
The new structure would be like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WekyP/

Comment: I tried that originally because I thought it was the best and most obvious solution. But then sometimes I get elements on their own row. You can't see it in the fiddle, but in my actual code the first 6 elements appear correctly split into two rows of 3, then the third row has a single element in the right hand column, then the 4th row has 3 elements, the 5th row has a single element in the right hand column etc. Any explanation for that behavior? Do I need to clear the floats or something similar?

Comment: It depends on a `.col-md-4`'s height. If it is possible for you to give all of them a fixed height (like `height: 400px)`, it will work. (Be sure not to use it globally on all  `.col-md-4`s, but give the parent row a special class and select the children with `.search-grid .col-md-4`.)

Comment: I did give it a special class before I saw you suggested it ;) setting to a fixed height of 200px worked beautiful for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why use column?  Put your results in a unordered list and float all listitems elements left, and fix their widths w/ css.

```
<div class="row">
    <ul>
        <li><div>fancy_result1</div></li>
        <li><div>fancy_result2</div></li>
        <li><div>fancy_result3</div></li>
        <li><div>fancy_result4</div></li>
        <li><div>fancy_result5</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What you have is a list of results.  Probably shouldn't artificially create the rows.

dirty sample: http://jsfiddle.net/55vZx

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap alone, there would be no way to get a `col` div to behave that way.  Think of a `row` as a table row (`tr`).  Anything inside that row will stay in that row, regardless of the number of things in rows before it. To achieve what you want, you would either:

A) Use some JS to re-distribute your col-md-4 divs within each row (take the ones you want to show and copy the first 3 into the first row, the next 3 into the second, etc...)

or

B) Move away from bootstrap and write some custom CSS to eliminate the need for rows (like just a series of divs all floated left)

Update:
In fact: if you just remove the containing `row` divs.. it seems to behave in the proper manner.  Note bootstrap wasn't written to work correctly all the time without the rows, so you might need to do some additional styling in edge cases.
See http://jsfiddle.net/9bHVf/13/

Comment: Hi Kenny, would you please take a look at the comment I left on the other answer and see if you have any explanation for the behavior I'm seeing? Thanks.

Comment: This has to do with bootstrap's styling on the `col-md-4` divs.  You really should just eliminate the rows and remove the col-md-4 classes and write some custom styling for what would have been the col-md-4 divs